# Add to cart doesn't work after pagination with AJAX is implemented

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem using AJAX in my shop.

I've just implemented pagination (Also using AJAX) and the add to cart doesn't work anymore.

It is really weird as if I will click on Add to cart twice and very fast, it works in some cases.

**Here is the add to cart function:**

```
$(".form-item").submit(function(e){
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
  button_content.html('Adaugare...'); //Loading button text
  $.ajax({ //make ajax request to cart_process.php
    url: "cart_process.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
    data: form_data
  }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success
    $("#cart-info").html(data.items); //total items in cart-info element
    button_content.html('Cumpara'); //reset button text to original text
    $(".cart-box").trigger( "click" ); //trigger click to update the cart box.
  })
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Here is one of the functions from pagination:**

```
function getresult(url) {
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data:  {rowcount:$("#rowcount").val(),name:$("#name").val(),code:$("#code").val()},
  success: function(data){ $("#toys-grid").html(data);}
   });
}
getresult("live_getresult.php");
```

I think there is a conflict between these two AJAX requests and it is really weird that it works sometimes when I click it fast and many times on add to cart button.

Also, it doesn't work at all when I'm on a different page than the first one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements that are AJAXed in, are `.form-item`s, then the event handler wont be bound to those new elements, you'll need to delegate the event via the document, change:

```
$(".form-item").submit(function(e) {
...
```

to:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form-item', function(e) {
...
```

Comment: @Alexandru be sure to properly thank Stuart by accepting this answer (the checkmark to the left), so your question can be closed as solved.